# Regex can contains only numeric and "-" character

Tags: regex

I want to match numeric numbers with "-" characater.

For example:

```
123-456 - Valid 
1-2-3-4 - Valid
223-213- - Invalid
-3423-3 - Invalid
ASD34-2 - Invalid
```

I'v tested this:

> ^([0-9]-?)*$

But not working properly.

Comment: Will `123---46` be valid? Or `34-`? E t.c. - be more specific

Comment: Nope. No repeated "-" character. And no, can not end with a "-" character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should match multiple `-` within the numbers, unlike the other answer:

```
^\d+(?:-\d+)*$
```

Comment: Edited - that should be fixed now. (This wasn't clear in the OP.)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty close not? Only the case with the dash on the end will pass. Instead of [0-9] you could use \d.

```
^\d(\d|-\d)*$
```

This one says at least one digit at start, optionally followed by more digits or an dash with at least one digit behind it
This won't match multiple following dashes like 12---34